# React Native Props Not Updating

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm pretty new to React and I'm running into an issue with updating my props in a container.  I'm updating my state using WebSockets and the props are being updated in my mapStateToProps function, but my componentWillReceiveProps is not being called despite that.

When the sockets emit, `updateGameVariables` calls an Action sending the emitted data, which then goes to my reducer which is using the Spread Operator to update state.  And then mapStateToProps logs the proper data (which is updating).

Here is the main file I am dealing with (everything is being properly imported I just wanted to cut down on code):

```
class GameList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1 !== r2})
        const { games } = props;
        this.state = {
            games: this.ds.cloneWithRows(games)
        }
        this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://localhost:9615',{ transports: ['websocket'], query: 'r_var=17' });
        this.socket.on('appGames', function(results){
            props.dispatch(updateGameVariables(results))
      });
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.setState({
            games: this.ds.cloneWithRows(nextProps.games)
        })
    }

    render() {
        let { games } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.list}>
                <ListView
                    dataSource={games}
                    renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => 
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <GameIntro key={rowID} game={rowData} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    }
                >
                </ListView>
        </View>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({games}){
    return {
        games: games.games, // Array
        // rand: Math.random()
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  let actions = bindActionCreators({ updateGameVariables });
  return { ...actions, dispatch };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GameList)
```

And here is the GameIntro component that is being referenced.

```
export default props => {
    let { game } = props;
    return (
        <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
            <View style={styles.game_timerow}>
                <Text style={styles.game_time}>{game.period} {game.minutes}:{game.seconds}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Also as a note, when I have the `rand: Math.random()` function uncommented everything updates properly.  And so I feel like react simply isn't picking up on updates to the games array.  Or I am just not understanding a core concept of React.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you console log anything inside `componentWillReceiveProps` to make sure it is really not being called?

Comment: @nbkhope yes I have, and its really not being called unless I have that `rand` line in there.

Comment: Well, did you console log anything in render()? The render function will be called again if there are new props or state. You have to know if your props/state are really changing.

Comment: Yeah I've done that as well, but nothing is being logged there either.  However I can see that the data is updated in mapStateToProps

Comment: Perhaps the definition of the socket variable on the component is causing the problem. Maybe React doesn't know about the change that was made because no props or state was changed. What does `updateGameVariables` change in the application state? Make sure in your reducer you are actually returning a new state with the new "games" variable.

Comment: `updateGameVariables` is updating some attributes (time remaining, score etc) on the objects that make up the games array. And in terms up returning new state, I'm returning `{...state, games: action.payload}` which I believe returns a new state.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are mixing React component state with Redux application state? Why not just use the Redux app state directly? Can you try using `setState({ games: ... })` whenever you receive new results through the socket? Start dealing with React component state ONLY to see if it works. Then, migrate to Redux app state after the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have a mutation problem in your reducer code, and because of that React see the games array as the same, then decide to not update the rendering. It explains why

```
rand: Math.random()
```

help React to realize that there is update in the props object and trigger re-render.

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html might help.